# jQuery - unique control over a class using onChange

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using jQuery colorpicker on an app.  When a color is selected and being selected, the color is displayed in a span class ".swatch".  However, when there are two color select options on a single page, the span.swatch will both display the same color as the color is being selected. (see screenshot).

Screenshot here: http://cl.ly/2MUU

Here is the code I'm using

```
jQuery('.colorselect').ColorPicker({
    onSubmit: function ( hsb, hex, rgb, el ) {
        jQuery(el).val(hex);
        jQuery(el).ColorPickerHide();
    },
    onBeforeShow: function () {
        jQuery(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        jQuery('.swatch').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$.each($('.colorselect'),function(){
    var $target = $(this);
    $(this).ColorPicker({
            onSubmit: function ( hsb, hex, rgb, el ) {
                           jQuery(el).val(hex);
                           jQuery(el).ColorPickerHide();
            },
            onBeforeShow: function () {
                     jQuery(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
            },
            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                     $target.find('.swatch').css('backgroundColor', '#'+hex);
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) { 
        jQuery(this).find('.swatch').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex); 
    }
```

This should work - Havent tried it myself though.

Comment: Good answer!  That actually solved a problem I had elsewhere.  But for this problem, it didn't work.  The .swatch is not a descendant as the .colorselect is an input field. It's like <input><span class="swatch"></span>